# A non-homogeneous linear differential equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the general solution of :
$$y''+y=\cos x\cos 2x$$

Comment: Try searching "non-homogeneous second order  linear ode" in google for how to solve these forms of ODEs.

Comment: Did you try anything? If you just want an answer, you can try on wolfram, else show us something what you have done ...

Comment: Hint: $$\cos x\cos2x=\frac12(\cos3x+\cos x).$$

Comment: The question does not show any research effort.

Comment: here is step by step solution from [Wolf](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o6htQ.png)

Comment: @experimentX - how did you do that?

Comment: @nbubis if you create W|A account they provide free 3 detailed solutions per day :)

Comment: @experimentX - From a purely CS point of view I find the process W|A preforms fascinating.

Comment: @nbubis i used to be web programmer ... I used to find it impossible :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

First find the homogeneous solution: $$y\to A\cos(x) + B\sin(x) $$
Then guess an in-homogeneous solution by first expressing the RHS as a sum of cosines:
$$\frac{1}{2}(\cos(x)+\cos(3x))$$
This gives you an indication of what your guess should look like. Because $\cos(x)$ is part of the homogeneous solution, you need another term to create the $\cos(x)$ in the RHS. One such term is $$y=x\sin(x)/2 \to y'' + y =\cos(x)$$
I think this should be enough to go on.